# Social media buttons wont work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Ive cant seem to figure this out, as far as I know this is always the way I have linked to my social media buttons but the links wont work. Here's the URL: http://fantasyaficionado.com/news/

```
<ul class="social">  

 <li class="facebook"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fantasyaficionado">facebook</a> </li>
 <li class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/FanAficionado">twitter</a></li>
 <li class="google"> <a href="http://google.com">google+</a></li>

</ul><!--social-->
```

The css is basically the same for all of these:

```
ul.social{
  float:right;
  li{display:inline-block;}
  margin-right:1%;
}

.twitter{
  text-indent:-9999px;
  background: url('images/mainsprite.png') no-repeat -99px -192px;
  width: 41px;
  height: 41px;
     @include breakpoint(tinyer) {
        background: url('images/mainsprite.png') no-repeat -90px -313px;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
     }
    &:hover{
     cursor:pointer;
     background: url('images/mainsprite.png') no-repeat -99px -239px;
     width: 41px;
     height: 41px;
        @include breakpoint(tinyer) {
          background: url('images/mainsprite.png') no-repeat -90px -341px;
          width: 24px;
          height: 24px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `text-indent:-9999px;` is the issue

Comment: what's the problem exactly?

Comment: I tried it without the text and it still wouldn't work. I can click on the text if I dont indent it but I cant have that text across the face of my buttons. Whats another way to get rid of the text while still trying to be semantic like.

Comment: JP- It wont follow the external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove your `text-indent` in your `li.facebook` and other `li`, and add following css

```
li.facebook a {
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: It worked but I dont understand why making the anchor tag a block element worked? Can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: to make the `a` tag perfectly fit your `li`, you have to add `width:100%;height:100%`, however, `a` tag is a inline element which won't apply these unless it turns to `block`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS

```
ul.social >li > a{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

Right now you only have the size of 100% for the facebook link, plus you're missing `display:block`, also you're repeating some CSS in your `.facebook`, `.twitter`, and `.google` classes, you can use a single rule like this to avoid code duplication:

```
ul.social > li{
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url("images/mainsprite.png") no-repeat;
    width: 41px;
    height: 41px;
}
```

Then just set the background position for each class